# Event Handling in Smalltalk(squeak)

Tags: events, event-handling, smalltalk, squeak

How can I create my own events in Smalltalk?  I am basically looking for some software events that can be triggered when some particular event happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In classic Smalltalk (supported by Squeak as a direct derivative of the original XEROX Parc image), you have a basic publish/subscribe model.  Look for "event" in the protocol browser for Object instances.

In modern Smalltalk, you can use catch/throw user-defined events using the Exception class and its subclasses.  See the class documentation for Exception for details.

You can also select the Announcements framework, available in Squeaksource, as a more flexible version of the classic event framework.

Answer (score 2):

To recap, events are based on the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) where a *subject* has *dependents* observing selected *events* on it.

This creates a relationship of [loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) among them.

In Squeak or Pharo in some method that knows both, the subject and the observer, you'd do it like this:

**Observation**

```
elevatorPanel when: #openDoorClicked send: #onOpenDoorClicked to: elevator
```

**Event Triggering**

On the other hand, with `self` being `elevatorPanel`:

```
self triggerEvent: #openDoorClicked
```

And you'll have `elevator` receiving the `onOpenDoorClicked` message.

Similarly, you can do it with arguments:

```
elevatorPanel when: #floorSelected: send: #onFloorSelected: to: elevator with: floorNumber
```

In which case you can trigger in two ways, first

```
self triggerEvent: #floorSelected:
```

Wich will make the `elevator` observer instance to receive the `onFloorSelected:` message with `floorNumber` as the argument.

And second, overriding that value at the triggering time

```
self triggerEvent: #floorSelected: with: aFresherFloorValue
```

In which case you'll also have `elevator` receiving the `onFloorSelected:` but with `aFresherFloorValue` instead of the `floorValue` captured during the observation setup.